# Accuracy of the some components' values

Tags: resistors

I have some questions about the accuracy of some electric components, especially for SMD components.
We can reveal that each SMD resistor has 1% or 5% or 0.5% of accuracy.
I wonder if the accuracy means 'just the absolute accuracy of the resistance', which means the temperature will not affect to accuracy, or not.

Comment: Do you have a datasheet for your resistors?

Comment: @ThePhoton I use Panasonic's High Precision Thick Film Chip Resistor 255Ohms, and the datasheet has just a power derating curve, not the affection to the resistance accuracy caused by temperature. The part is PB6D2550V. I only know that TCR of the resistor is 50*10^-6 per celcius degree.

Comment: Related: [Is the total resistance of a resistor static once the tolerance is applied?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/254423/is-the-total-resistance-of-a-resistor-static-once-the-tolerance-is-applied)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know, the tolerance specification of a resistor is usually given as the initial accuracy of the resistor when it is delivered to the customer, measured at 25 C.

This is supported by [a document](http://www.vishay.com/docs/49873/49873_sg2113.pdf) from Vishay:

[image]

I would expect to be able to find a similar clarification in some documentation from Panasonic or any other reputable resistor manufacturer, but I couldn't find it with a few minutes looking around their website.

> I wonder if the accuracy means 'just the absolute accuracy of the resistance', which means the temperature will not affect to accuracy, or not.

The change in resistance due to temperature is a further error beyond the initial tolerance specification.

Comment: I have some work I have to solve now about the error rate of the resistors rather than capacitors, with your related question I apparently understood what the tolerance means. I'm using a 50W dc-dc converter and the datasheet of the converter demanded to use 0.5% tolerance resistor as the trim resistor which determines the voltage of the output voltage. Your answer makes clear about the reason of the use of the high precision resistors... I will talk about another topic later.